# how to display input box for n times in lightning component, where value for n is given by user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

how to display input box for n times in lightning component, where value for n is given by user. Is it possible. and I have a code for it but not working properly. can anyone help to resolve this

```
<aura:component >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="keywords" type="List" default="[{value:''},{value:''},{value:''},{value:''}]" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.keywords}" var="item" indexVar="i">
    <lightning:input label="Keyword" value="{!item.value}" />
</aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
      alert('1');  
      var keywords = component.get("v.keywords").map(item => item.value);
        alert('1');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the sample code to dynamically create the input fields based on user input.

```
<aura:component >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="keywords" type="List" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.keywords}" var="item">
    <lightning:input label="Keyword" data-id="{!item.id}" value="{!item.value}" />
</aura:iteration>
</aura:component>


({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    let inputNumber = prompt('Please enter no. of inputs');
    let keywords = [];
    for(var i=0; i<inputNumber; i++){
        keywords.push({id:i, value:""});
    };
    component.set("v.keywords",keywords);
}
})
```